# Javascript Check Form: Nothing happening

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a js form validation check but for some reasons nothing is happening when im writing the function here's the code so when my email value is "" its supposed to display the alert message but its not displaying:

```html
<form onsubmit="checkForm()" method="post">
  <input class="test" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="10" name="firstname" placeholder="➡️ Write Your First
 Name"></input>
  <input class="test" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder=" Write your Last Name"></input>
  <input class="test" id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="✉️ Write your Best Email"></input>
  <!--<textarea class="test" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Tell us more about yourself"></textarea>-->
  <script>
    function checkForm(form) {
      const getEmailValue = document.getElementById(email);
      if (getEmailValue === "") {
        alert('you need to fullfill');
      }
    }
  </script>

  <div id="buttoncenter">
    <button type="submit" class="button">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Please don't post code with `>` before it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the argument to `getElementById`, and get the `value` property.

The validation function should also return `false` when the form shouldn't be submitted, and you need to use a `return` statement in `onsubmit` so that this will be used.

```js
function checkForm(form) {
  const getEmailValue = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if (getEmailValue === "") {
    alert('you need to fullfill');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkForm()" method="post">
  <input class="test" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="10" name="firstname" placeholder="➡️ Write Your First
 Name"></input>


  <input class="test" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder=" Write your Last Name"></input>

  <input class="test" id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="✉️ Write your Best Email"></input>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```